# Voltage Rating of a device

Tags: voltage, maximum-ratings, piezo-buzzer

When a buzzer 'rating' is 3v, What does that exactly mean? When my buzzer 'input range' is from 3-10v?What does 'rating of a device tell us? Can someone differentiate between the two parameters above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I heard something was "rated for 3V", I would try to avoid exceeding that voltage. "Rating" refers to a safe boundary, and that boundary is usually a maximum - things are more likely to break from too much power than too little. If the buzzer did not work just below 3V, then one might risk going just above.

The input range is the range of values for which the device will operate correctly. Going below 3V is unlikely to cause any problems except (temporary) silence. Supplying a higher voltage closer to the middle may result in better operation, and everything will be fine up to 10V. The 10V need not be the upper safe boundary, though the absolute maximum will usually be somewhere close to the upper limit of the input range. Exceeding *that* increases the risk of loud buzzing being replaced by (permanent) silence.

Comment: http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/audio-products/alarms-buzzers-and-sirens/720967

Comment: in the link above,There are two fields, Voltage 'rated' and Voltage 'range'. My doubt is if a device is rated at 3v, How can it have a range upto 30v?

Comment: I said what I would assume if there was no other information. The table on that page answers your question - here, the rating is the target value rather than the maximum, and is always smaller than the maximum of the range. You can approach the highest number listed without melting the part.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time off to answer this question! That's what i initially thought , but wasn't too sure .

Comment: Any time! You can mark an answer as accepted unless you want to receive more of them.

Answer (score 0):

A datasheet, or some information on where you saw this would be nice...

A rating of 3 Volts means that the device is intended to operate from a 3 volt power supply.

An input range of 3 - 10 volts means that the device will work on any power supply voltage within that range.

Comment: http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/audio-products/alarms-buzzers-and-sirens/720967

Comment: in the link above,There are two fields, Voltage 'rated' and Voltage 'range'. My doubt is if a device is rated at 3v, How can it have a range upto 30v?